# Show last uploaded files from $_FILES

Tags: php, mysql, session, file-upload

**What I've got so far:** I have a functioning system to upload multiple images at the same time, this is its flow:

1. `upload.php:` It displays an HTML form so that the user can select &
   upload desired images.
2. `upload-script.php`: It's called by **upload.php**, it receives each
   image as a `$_FILE`, it uploads its metadata to MYSQL, and the file
   itself to the server. Then, it displays all uploaded images, with a
   textarea below, asking the user to input the description of each
   image.
3. `details.php`: It receives the description of each image, and
   uploads it to the database.

**Where I'm stuck:** Basically, my problem is linking the image with its corresponding description. This is a line of code I can't finish, from 3) `details.php`:

```
if(!mysqli_query($db, "UPDATE `imagenes` SET `descripcion`= '".$_POST['descripcion']."'  WHERE `id`= '".$_SESSION['id']."'"))
```

**The problem:** As you can probably imagine, the source of the problem is WHERE `id` = $_session.

Below are two pastebin links to files 2) and 3), in case it helps:

Upload-script.php: http://pastebin.com/uW72esnV
Details.php: http://pastebin.com/QtCuNh3Q

Database structure:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the "tid" after the file upload, line 69 (int)mysqli_insert_id($db)

Try using tid as array key for description inputs:

```
<input type="text" name="imageDescription[<?php echo $tid; ?>]" />
```

will be something like

```
<input type="text" name="imageDescription[44]" />
```

Then in details.php made the following iteration

```
foreach ($_POST['imageDescription'] as $tid => $desription) {
    // update `files` set description = $description where tid = $tid
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time, I added the foreach in details.php, but I always had a hard time understanding associative arrays;
Is this what you're suggesting?

    `@$tr2 .= "<td><textarea name='descripcion'[".$row_tid."]></textarea></td>";`

I mean, do you suggest retrieving the TID from MYSQL and putting it in each name=description[tid]?

Comment: yes. Then in details.php you will have `foreach ($_POST['descripcion'] as $tid => $description)`

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in the code. Maybe there is something in the "deleted" code in pastebin. hint: you could dump whole $_POST to see what have been send :)